# Errors installing steam on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, steam, nouveau

I'm using xubuntu 17.10 64-bit, and i'm having difficulty installing steam, i've used apt-get, software centre and downloading directly from the steam website. When I type `steam` in terminal, I get the following error message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```